# Cannot parse the data of the dict to pass on to an function

Tags: python

i am currently trying to build a api using flask. I have a users.csv file where i have three column of data which are hour,minute and comment. I am reading this csv using pandas library and then converting it into dict, to further access and use it in function to process the data which is the core logic of api.

I have the the users.csv file

```
hour,minute,comment
11,50,"abcd"
18,16,"xyz"
19,12,"efgh"
20,05,"ijkl"
```

I can assess the /logic, but i am unable to retrive the data of the from the dict.
When i return the data from the following code:

```
    def get(self):
        data = pd.read_csv('users2.csv')  
        data = data.to_dict() 
        return {'data': data}, 200
```

I get the following output:

```
{"data": 
{"hour": {"0": 11, "1": 18, "2": 19, "3": 20}, 
"minute": {"0": 50, "1": 16, "2": 12, "3": 5}, 
"comment": {"0": "abcd", "1": "xyz", "2": "efgh", "3": "ijkl"}}}
```

I tried to access the data by using the following code but could not get to any conclusion:

```
comment_filter = data['comment']
hours_filter = data['hour']
minute_filter = data['minute']
```

I would like to take value of each index and further process it in loop with my core logic function, which i cannot do. How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to them by converting your index to string. for example:

```
hour_at_index = dict["data"]["hour"][str(index)]
```

Comment: Actually, i skipped the part of converting pd processed data in to dict... Instead took that pd processed data and got the parsed the value using `str(data['hour'][i])`